# .NET Regular Expression: How to get a text enclosed by two tags

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I am working with ASP.NET and need to manage with a string typed by the user in order to extract some information. The user enters a normal text, words and numbers, but sometimes he may type a mathematical expression in MATHML, these expressions are always an xml string enclosed by the  tag.
I want to extract from the typed text every math segment.
For example, let's consider the user typed this text:

```
string input = "My name is Dorry and here is a math expression: <math>---some math1---</math> ah, there is another expression: <math>---some math2---</math> and do not forget this too <math>---some math3---</math>.".
```

Well, The first regex solution I came up with is this:

```
string pattern1 = @"\<math(.+)\<\/math\>";
```

To get matches I obviousely use:

```
Regex r = new Regex(pattern1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string[] res = r.Matches(input);
```

And it seemd working, too bad, it does not because this expression, instead of getting me an array (using Reges.Matches) filled with three strings ("---some math1---", "---some math2---", "---some math3---"); it gets me an array with one element only: "---some math1--- ah, there is another expression: ---some math2--- and do not forget this too ---some math3---". Can you see? it takes the first  and the last  and merges everything in the middle WITHOUT CARING of some other  or  elements in the way!

Well, I suppose this is a well known issue about regular expressions; is there a solution? how to tell the regex engine to be a little more... aware?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: XML parsing with Regex? It hurts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Yeah you're right but here I do not have a well formed xml tree, here I must manage with an hybrid structure made of some xml segments spread all over the place like salt and pepper...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go..

```
string pattern1 = @"\<math[\s\S]*?<\/math\>";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection res = r.Matches(input);
```

Nick

Answer (score 1):

1. Using regular expressions for matching XML-/HTML-like tags is usually a bad idea and very error-prone. I don't know if the balanced groups .NET regexes provide solve this, so just be warned.
2. Your problem has bitten many many others before - regexes are greedy by default. `.+` can match everything (including `</math>`), so it matches the whole input. Then, because the regex did not match completely, it starts backtracing until the rest of the regex can match. And so the `</math>` subpattern matches only the last closing tag. To make the regex non-greedy, add a `?` after the `+` (or `*` for that matter).

Comment: Well, I found a correct pattern... about what you said... I'll be aware of it and research more to better understand where regex is considered a good solution for and a good practice. Thank you for your information

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the .NET BCL Regex class, you should be able to use balanced groups to achieve what you need:

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups

Answer (score 0):

You can use <math>[\s\S]*?</math> regex. It worked fine with the example string provided by you.
It gave me 3 matches as follows :

<math>---some math1---</math>

<math>---some math2---</math>

<math>---some math3---</math>

I hope this is what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you need:

```
  <math>.*?</math>
```

It matches every pair of **math** tags.

If the opening tag might contain attributes, use this regex instead:

```
  <math\b[^><]*>.*?</math>
```